# Iterating over range(0,len(temp),-1) doesn't work

Tags: python, if-statement

I have the following code which does not enter the loop and I can't understand why.

```
python file.py 1111100000000
```

Code:

```
import argparse

p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument("bits", help = "array_of_bits")
args = p.parse_args()
bits = args.bits

temp = []

for i in bits:
    temp.append([int(i)])

print (temp)

fin = []
j = 0

for i in range(0,len(temp),(-1)):
    if ( (temp[i] == 0) ):
        fin.extend(temp[j].append(temp[i]))
    if ( len(temp[i]) != 1 ):
        fin.extend(temp[j].append(temp[i]))

j = j + 1

print (fin)
```

What I wanted to get is:

```
[[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]]
[[10010], [10010], [100]
```

But instead I get this:

```
[[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]]
[[]]
```

Comment: Why do you pass `(-1)` to `range`?

Comment: Your code is quite a mess. Your indentation is off, you are mixing `extend` with `append` and your `for i in range` will never work.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is the `range` you're iterating over in your `for` loop:

```
for i in range(0,len(temp),(-1)):
```

`range(0,len(temp),(-1))` is an empty range, therefore the loop gets never executed.

Your range would start with 0 and produce items smaller than `len(temp)`, but in steps of `-1` i.e. counting downwards from 0. This way it could never ever reach its target value, because `len` is always positive.